# std::ofstream set precision for Floating point format

Tags: c++, ofstream

I need to write float type with 6 digit precision into file.
This code does not work correctly as i expected:

```
int main() {

    std::ofstream ofs("1.txt", std::ofstream::out);
    if (ofs.is_open() == false) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open file... 1.txt" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    time_t t_start, t_end;
    time(&t_start);
    sleep(1);
    time(&t_end);
    float elapsed = difftime(t_end, t_start);   
    ofs<<"Elapsed time= " << std::setprecision(6) <<elapsed<< "(s)"<<std::endl;        
    ofs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Elapsed time= 1(s)
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/):

```
ofs << "Elapsed time= " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6)
    << elapsed << "(s)"
    << std::endl;
```

Further [`difftime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) returns a double not a float.

> `double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0);`
>
> The `difftime()` function returns the number of seconds elapsed between time *time1* and time *time0*, represented as a *double*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert `std::fixed` into the stream if you want `0.000000`, along the lines of:

```
ofs << "Elapsed time = "
    << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed << elapsed << " (s)"
    << std::endl;
```

This gives you:

```
Elapsed time = 0.000000 (s)
```